# cocos creator 1.6 SDKBox

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocoscreator

I try to add AdMob to my application in cocos creator 1.6. I did it along this tutorial: http://docs.sdkbox.com/en/qa/cocos_creator/ but I'm getting error if I try to run the simulator:

JS Exception- sdkbox is not defined.

It is possible to build application for android, but it show just only black screen. I guess it is due to the error.

Is there necessary to setup anything manually or it is just bug in this release?

Thanks for answers.
Petr

Comment: I solve it, There was a problem with a default template. I switched to a binary template and it seems that it is working good.
Also there is necessary to run AdMob on mobile device. It is not running on web platform.

Comment: If you solved it yourself, please [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with your solution. Don't edit the title and add `SOLVED` to it, that's not how it's done on Stack Overflow.